# What does SQL Server trace flag 253 do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

In another question I was trying to research how to control SQL Server's query plan caches:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593749/is-there-an-equivalent-of-optionrecompile-or-with-recompile-for-an-entire-c

...and I found trace flag 253 via this article:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic837613-146-1.aspx

The article is correct, if I run DBCC TRACEON(253) and then a number of queries, I can manually check the query plan cache and see that plans have **not** been inserted.  If I run DBCC TRACEOFF(253), query plans are cached as normal.

So my question is...what else does this flag do?  Does anybody know the official story?

Comment: As you've probably discovered, there doesn't appear to be any full documented list of trace flags available (even outside of BOL).  I have a feeling that MS has only documented the few that are common and stable enough for a majority of users, and the rest get used during support tickets to diagnose issues.

Comment: Agreed.  We're not going to use this anyway.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/trace+flags/70131/

Answer (score 1):

As you say and as is mentioned in [Jon Seigels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596587/what-does-sql-server-trace-flag-253-do#comment7733080_2596587) comment, it:

> Prevents ad-hoc query plans to stay in cache.

It *shouldn't* do anything else. However, as is also stated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/6739df93-7339-453f-ad3d-88321c1d919c) for trace flags, generally:

> Trace flags cause the database engine to execute alternate code paths that may not have been as rigorously tested or have a specific purpose and may have side effects that are unpredictable.

Given this is info from a MVP who claims to have heard from a member of the product team, it looks to be as official as it gets. Especially since Microsofts [own documentation on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx) doesn't contain all trace flags that can be found on the net - like Jon Seigels link in his comment.